# Execute specific service for wsdl2java

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have placed following plugin in maven. I want to create java client code either for MyWSDLService or MyOtherWSDLService.

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
       <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${cxf.version}</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>generate-sources</id>
               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
               <configuration>
             <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>    <wsdlOptions>
         <wsdlOption>
             <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
             <serviceName>MyWSDLService</serviceName>
         </wsdlOption>
         <wsdlOption>
             <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/myOtherService.wsdl</wsdl>
             <serviceName>MyOtherWSDLService</serviceName>
         </wsdlOption>
     </wsdlOptions>                </configuration>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Could some one help me with that..?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your requireement correct, but maybe profiles can help you

Comment: @Jens , profiles might help , but I just want to tell from command line while running phase or goal of maven

Answer (score 0):

To select the wsdl, to generate code for, you need to specifiy the default option inside the configuration element:

```
<defaultOptions>
      <bindingFiles>
          <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/jaxb/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
      </bindingFiles>
      <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
  </defaultOptions>
```

Or you could just generate the code for all wsdl files:

```
<configuration>
  <defaultOptions>
      <bindingFiles>
          <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/jaxb/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
      </bindingFiles>
      <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
  </defaultOptions>
  <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
  <includes>
      <include>*Service.wsdl</include>
  </includes>
</configuration>
```